# Installing Linux alongside Windows without boot managers

Tags: windows, dual-boot, grub, boot-loader

Can I install Linux alongside Windows on another drive and choose what OS to boot just through UEFI?
I have two disks: SSD and HDD. And so I want to install Linux OS on a partition on HDD while being able to use Windows on my SSD. I'm asking this question because I heard a lot about disadvantages of dual-booting from a single drive.
Will it be better to install Linux on a separate partition on a SSD? And what is the better way to maintain multiple OS's on a system?

Comment: Note that if Ubuntu or any official flavor or unofficial flavor that uses the Ubiquity installer will install the grub2 UEFI boot folder & .efi boot files into the first drive's ESP, on your SSD. If / (root) is on SSD then the Linux install will boot & load large apps quicker, but once in RAM, be the same speed. You can have /home or data partition(s) then on HDD for both operating systems as data not used or loaded as much. If installing on HDD make sure you have gpt partitioning and an ESP - efi system partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My experience is that there's a lot of hang-overs from legacy boot which mean people will often recommend using a separate drive.  Since the rise of UEFI I've found that most of those issues have gone away.  There is one worth mentioning:

Windows has been known to completely reformat UEFI partitions unexpectedly.  This is most likely to do with a Windows update or some form of system-restore.  I've only seen it in rare cases but it does happen.

One other caveat that I've experienced more recently... Some machines with SSHD (Hybrid solid-state / hard disk) can perform badly particularly if you spend a lot of time under one OS; the other may subsequently run *slow*.  That's because the SSHD will optimise for one OS at the expense of another.

If you are happy switching between OS with your motherboard's boot option then that should be fine.  Alternatively boot using grub and use that as your boot menu.